# Android two-way databinding cannot get event onCheckedChanged to fire

Tags: android, android-databinding

I can't get the OnCheckedChangeListener to fire unless I call executePendingBindings. But then, if I do that, the setChecked event in Item.java does not get called.

How can I get both setChecked and OnCheckedChangeListener to get called?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.abc.twowaydatabinding.Item" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="@={item.checked}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Item.java

```
import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;

public class Item extends BaseObservable {
    private String name;
    private Boolean checked;
    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    @Bindable
    public Boolean getChecked() {
        return this.checked;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }
    public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.checked);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Item item;
    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    Switch switch_test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        item = new Item();

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setItem(item);

        switch_test = findViewById(R.id.switch_test);

        ///binding.executePendingBindings(); -->this will fire OnCheckedChangeListener

        switch_test.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't too surprising to me as I know that click listeners work this way (there can only be one). One way I've dealt with clicks is `onTouchHandler`, but I think what would be better here is to use `item.addOnPropertyChangedCallback()` instead of `setOnCheckedChangedListener()`. One of the benefits of databinding is that you can implement MVVM pattern where the ViewModel is decoupled from UI specifics.  In this case, you could change the implementation from `Switch` to something else and your activity code wouldn't have to change (and you could eliminate the `findViewById()` call).